# class hierarchy methods when invoking from other classes

Tags: java, object, hierarchy

First off this is a pretty basic problem, but i just cant seem to get it,
ok so here is a general overview of my program

```
       |class A |
       |new B();|
       |new C();|
      /         \
     /           \
|Class B |     |Class C     |
|new D();|     |method E(){}|
    |
|Class D         |
|Invokes method E|
```

This is my programs hierarchy and I want to invoke the non static method E from class D, without creating a new instance of class C, is there a way to do this or do i have to restructure my class hierarchy.

**EDIT:**Here is real code to display my problem(without a class B though):

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JSplitPane;

public class TheFrame extends JFrame{
public TheFrame(){
    setTitle("Suduku Solver");
    add(new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT,
            new TextLabel(),  new ChangeButton()));
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(300,300);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new TheFrame();
}
}


import javax.swing.JLabel;
public class TextLabel extends JLabel{
public TextLabel(){
    setText("This is the Label");
}
public void ChangeLabel(){
    setText("Changed Label");
}
}

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
public class ChangeButton extends JButton {
public ChangeButton(){
    setText("Click to change Label");
    addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            //Invoke TextLabel changeText method here
        }
    });
}
}
```

i would like to invoke the changeText method by clicking the button

Comment: Your ascii diagram is unclear. Could you post actual code instead?

Comment: You could pass the instance of `C` class from `A` to `B` class. Then, pass this instance to `D` class and invoke the `method E` in `D` class without having to create the instance in `D` class.

Answer (score 1):

You can't invoke a non-static method without an instance. That's "non negotiable".

You'll have to rework your class structure.

Answer (score 1):

You could inject `C` class to `D` using constructor or setters.
This is an example with constructor injection.

```
class A {
 A() {
   C c = new C();
   B b = new B(c);
 }
}

class B {
 B(C c) {
   D d = new D(C c);
 }
}

class D {
 private C c;

 D(C c) {
   this.c = c;
 }

 public void methodThatCallsE() {
  c.E();
 }
}
```

This way you can call method `E` without having to create an object of `C` in `D`.

You could modify your `ChangeButton` class to receive any `JLabel` object.

```
public class ChangeButton extends JButton {
       private JLabel jlabel;
       public ChangeButton(JLabel jlabel){
          this.jlabel = jlabel;
          setText("Click to change Label");
          addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
              @Override
              public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                  jlabel.setText("new Text");
              }
          });
      }
  }
```

And then, `TheFrame` class would look like this.

```
public class TheFrame extends JFrame{
public TheFrame(){
    setTitle("Suduku Solver");
    JLabel jlabel = new TextLabel();
    add(new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT,
            jlabel,  new ChangeButton(jlabel)));
...
```

Comment: yes this is one way i could do it but i was looking for a simpler way rather than making a long chain of references

Comment: About this line `add(new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT,
            new TextLabel(),  new ChangeButton()));`. I think that you need to somehow pass the `new TextLabel()` object to the `new ChangeButton()` object. Why don't you pass it in `ChangeButton` constructor?